# PERL Dancer stdout capture

Tags: perl, dancer

I'm trying to use Dancer to make an app that executes a process which I write to and read from. In my test this works fine outside of Dancer but when I run in dancer I cannot capture the output from the process I spawn.

For example when I try the following

```
package My::App;
use Dancer ':syntax';
set serializer => 'JSON';
our $VERSION = '0.1';
use IPC::Run3;

get '/encode' => sub {
    my ($out, $err);
    my $in = 'test';
    run3 'cat', \$in, \$out, \$err;
    return $out;
}
```

Instead of capturing the output in $out it just gets printed to the console.

This is happening when running the Dancer app using the built in web server.

Comment: What about when you use a server like say [Starman](http://metacpan.org/module/Starman) ?

Comment: @gideon I fired it up in Starman and was able to capture the output. I also tried plackup and had success with that. So the question then is how are those environments different from just running app.pl and having it handled via Dancer::Handler::Standalone